# How can I animate pie charts in ARKit - Swift

Tags: swift, arkit

I’m currently working on creating interactive graphs in ARKit and have been using extruded UIBezierPaths to form each of the 2 slices that make up the pie chart. I’m now attempting to add animations to the bezier paths so that on the click of a button, the arc length animates and either grows or shrinks to reflect the new percentage. I have seen resources for using CAShapeLayer but many of them do not work for me because they were written in Obj-C or contain frameworks that don't work with today's ARKit.

The code I'm currently using to create the 2 parts of the graph is this:

```
func generateGraph(_ node: SCNNode, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, percent: Float, name: String, imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, color1: FirebaseColors, color2: FirebaseColors) {

    let r: Float  = 30.0
    let modelHeight: Float = 0.05
    let modelWidth: Float = 0.05

    let big = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(modelWidth/2 + r/8), y: CGFloat(modelHeight/2 + r/8)), radius: CGFloat(r), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2 * Double(percent / 100)), clockwise: true)
    big.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(modelWidth/2 + r/8), y: CGFloat(modelHeight/2 + r/8)))
    big.close()

    let small = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(modelWidth/2 + r/8), y: CGFloat(modelHeight/2 + r/8)), radius: CGFloat(r), startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2 * Double(percent / 100)), endAngle: CGFloat(0), clockwise: true)
    small.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(modelWidth/2 + r/8), y: CGFloat(modelHeight/2 + r/8)))
    small.close()

    let bigShape = SCNShape(path: big, extrusionDepth: 20)
    let smallShape = SCNShape(path: small, extrusionDepth: 20)

    let bigMat = SCNMaterial()
    let smallMat = SCNMaterial()

    bigMat.diffuse.contents = color1.convertToUI
    smallMat.diffuse.contents = color2.converToUI

    let bigNode = SCNNode(geometry: bigShape)
    let smallNode = SCNNode(geometry: smallShape)

    let scaleFactor = 0.001
    bigNode.scale = SCNVector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
    smallNode.scale = SCNVector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)

    bigNode.eulerAngles.x = .pi / 2
    smallNode.eulerAngles.x = .pi / 2

    let mainNodeToAdd = SCNNode()
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white

    mainNodeToAdd.opacity = 0.0
    mainNodeToAdd.geometry = planeGeometry
    mainNodeToAdd.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
    mainNodeToAdd.runAction(self.fadeAction)

    node.addChildNode(mainNodeToAdd)

    bigNode.position = SCNVector3(x: mainNodeToAdd.position.x, y: mainNodeToAdd.position.y + 0.01, z: mainNodeToAdd.position.z)
    smallNode.position = SCNVector3(x: mainNodeToAdd.position.x, y: mainNodeToAdd.position.y + 0.01, z: mainNodeToAdd.position.z)

    node.addChildNode(bigNode)
    node.addChildNode(smallNode)
    bigNode.name = name
    smallNode.name = name
}
```

How can I animate the changes in percentage so that my graphs can be used in ARKit?